# Why does Keycloak use a Session-Cookie instead of JWT Authorization Header

Tags: authentication, oauth, jwt, keycloak, openid-connect

I am using Keycloak for a microservices architecture.
When I want to access a protected resource I am shown the Keycloak login form and can log in. I get redirected to the resource after login. In the request header I can see that the header `Cookie: mongo-express=s%3AVpTxrBrZp_bb1kpZOuCo6nitgpTzI0YJ.6OS1ttu4hjcnut%2FG6zdyDnLk2B%2FrEmMEEw9jy2rCUrE; SESSION=510eb294-493e-4cb6-9cb8-1e09604a7fc7` is set.
When I try to access the resource with an `Authorization: Bearer ...` header (e.g. from Postman with a previously requestet JWT) I am not able to access the resource. Instead I am shown the login form again.

How can I configure Keycloak to use JWT instead of a Session in the header after login or at least accept Authorization header with Bearer token?

Answer (score 0):

You write:

> When I want to access a protected resource I am shown the Keycloak login form and can log in. I get redirected to the resource after login.

This leads me to assume you're using a browser and issuing a GET request. I'm assuming the browser is using the [OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Grant Type](https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/authorization-code/), and so the tokens are exchanged between the client (the web server) and the Keycloak server. And *not* between the web browser and the web server. This is a decision that was made by the team developing the "protected resource" and not something you can change without changing the source code of the "protected resource".

You also write:

> In the request header I can see that the header `Cookie: mongo-express=s%3AVpTxrBrZp_bb1kpZOuCo6nitgpTzI0YJ.6OS1ttu4hjcnut%2FG6zdyDnLk2B%2FrEmMEEw9jy2rCUrE; SESSION=510eb294-493e-4cb6-9cb8-1e09604a7fc7` is set.

If you start a browser form scratch (or use e.g. "New Incognito Window" in Chrome or "New Private Window" in Firefox) I'm pretty sure you'll see that in the response to the very first GET request to the protected resource, you'll find a `Set-Cookie` HTTP header in the server *response* (presumably the one that redirects to the OAuth2 server). This is just how the protected resource manages its sessions. Not much you can do about that, I'm affraid.

Comment: Actually I am also the team developing the protected resource (OAuth2 Resource Server). How would I be able to change the code to enable token exchange to the web browser? I am using Spring Security and Keycloak as OAuth2 IDP.
I assume that when you are talking about the protected resource you are talking about the OAuth2 Resource Server (which in my case is a Spring API Gateway)? Why would I want to manage sessions there when I want to have a stateless server? I am not handling sessions there. Or do you mean Keycloak by protected resource?
Thanks for your advice @Peter V. Mørch

Comment: What I want to achieve is:

Web Browser ---Request---> Gateway (Resource Server) ---Redirect (to Login)---> Web Browser ---Authenticate---> Keycloak (IDP) ---Token--> Gateway ---Relay Token---> Web Browser ---Request with Token---> Gateway

Comment: You'll have to implement [Authorization Code Flow with Proof Key for Code Exchange (PKCE)](https://auth0.com/docs/flows/concepts/auth-code-pkce) in the browser instead and send the JWT access token to your server *and verify on the server that the token is valid and issued/signed by your particular OAuth2 server*. Don't know how to do that last bit with Spring. Be careful though. Now all of a sudden all JavaScript on the page (ads, 3rd party libs, malicious browser extensions) has access to your tokens.